# How to move the "Main navigation" in the Bartik theme?

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 8, with the Bartik theme, I want to put the "Main navigation" tabs of the "Primary menu" region, on the top right, beside the "Site branding" block.

If I just move the "Main navigation" to the Header region, the tabs are lost.
I want to preserve the tabs.

How do I do it?

Comment: Please not put tags in title (unless they are a natural part of sentence), and try to phrase title as a question.

Answer (score 0):

First the main navigation is a block. Under Structure->Blocks you'll see Navigation. Move it to where it makes sense to you. Secondly Structure->menu is where you determine what items appear in your menu.